# Formatting Arrays of Objects into Objects (ES6 Way)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json

I am trying to create a pretty Objects of arrays but this come instead.

```
{
    "label": [
        "Instagram"
    ],
    "value": [
        "@username"
    ]
}
```

So, how can I change it? What I want is to be like this

```
{
    "label": "instagram",
    "value": "@username"
},
```

I don't know how it happened, but my guess is it was the result of me using formik to define initialValues of a complex nested array from strapi. I was using array.map to map the objects. Hence perhaps thats why it was so messy.

So what is the solution for this? Formatting Arrays of Arrays into Objects? Merging? Converting? I have no idea what it was called. Thanks in advance for anybody replying this.

(updated) The initialValues:

```
const formik = useFormik({
enableReinitialize: true,
initialValues: {
  name: vendor?.name || '',
  description: vendor?.description || '',
  company: {
    social_media: [
      {
        label: vendor.company?.social_media.map((x) => x.label) || '',
        value: vendor.company?.social_media.map((x) => x.value) || ''
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

Comment: You haven't shown any of the code that resulted in that object, so there is no way to help.

Comment: Next time onwards please try something first ,otherwise it seems like, here is my question solve it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `for..in` and array `join` method

```js
const data = {
  "label": [
    "Instagram"
  ],
  "value": [
    "@username"
  ]
};

for (let keys in data) {
  data[keys] = data[keys].join(',')

};

console.log(data)
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir for your answer, using .join('') clean up the messy array inside array problem I faced before. Now, I have a pretty array of objects just as I wanted to be.

Comment: It's not me. I am still a new user and i need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote either upvote or downvote. I have accepted it as best answer though

Answer (score 0):

Array.map returns an array if you don't want any object use Array.foreach

Or

Use [...Array.map()]

```
    label: [...vendor.company?.social_media.map((x) => x.label)] 
    value: [...vendor.company?.social_media.map((x) => x.value)
```

Comment: you can't use `map` with objects

Comment: But he mentioned he is using .map which is making it messey

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I have tried your solution but it doesn't work on Formik's InitialValues. The other solution using .join('') solved my problem though.